# How can I shorten this code to rotate a line segment around its center?

Tags: function-construction, geometry

I have a list of line segments stored in the form:

```
{ {{x11,y11},{x12,y12}} , {{x21,y21},{x22,y22}} , ... , {{xn1,yn1},{xn2,yn2}} }
```

Now I want to rotate all of them by 90 degrees about their own centers. To do that I wrote a pure function like this

```
{{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.(#[[1]] - (#[[1]] + #[[2]])/2) + (#[[1]] + #[[2]])/2,
{{0, -1}, {1, 0}}.(#[[2]] - (#[[1]] + #[[2]])/2) + (#[[1]] + #[[2]])/2} &
```

As you can see this is pretty lengthy compare to the simplicity of my request. But I do not have enough *Mathematica* experience to shorten it. So can anyone help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something along the lines of `Rotate[Line[pts], angle, Mean[pts]]`:

```
g = Graphics[Line[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]];
rot = l : Line[pts_] :> Rotate[l, Pi/2, Mean[pts]];

Show[g, g /. rot]
```

[image]

I believe that `Rotate` and family are `Graphics`/`Graphics3D` directives which are only processed when they are rendered. If you need to access actual rotated values of the points, you can use `RotationTransform` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 2}]
```

Whole rotation

```
Graphics[{Line[data], {Red, Rotate[Line[data], Pi/2]}}]
```

[image]

Single segment rotation

```
Graphics[{Line[data], {Red, Rotate[Line[#], Pi/2]} & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This does not appear to rotate line segments around their centers, as asked by the O.P.

Comment: @whuber added that too

Comment: The third argument of `Rotate` (your `Mean[]`) isn't needed here b/c the rotation is made around the bounding box center by default, and that's the line center point

Comment: @belisarius I tried that - it did not look right. They were not rotations about segment centers.

Comment: Sure?  http://i.stack.imgur.com/UmMgO.png

Comment: @belisarius yep. you can see it is "almost" perfect. http://i.stack.imgur.com/GnIXZ.png

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov That's a PlotRange problem http://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvy4I.png

Comment: @belisarius yep you are right. strange that PlotRange->All did not help - which i checked. Anyway I fixed it. Did not put PlotRange there though, - he can figure it out from the comments.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow you guys. Here's a little apparatus: `Graphics[{Gray, l = Line[data], Blue, Text["x", Scaled@{.5, .5}], Rotate[l, Pi/2], Red, Text["x", m = Mean[data]], Rotate[l, Pi/2, m]}]` (edit: it looks like the mechanism is clearer if we replace the random line with a rectangle, in which case both rotate equally)

Answer (score 2):

Had `Rotate[]`/`RotationTransform[]` not been available, here's a possible alternative:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123, Method -> "MKL"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            segs = Arrow[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {5, 2, 2}]]];

Graphics[{{Blue, segs},
          {Red, segs /. s_?MatrixQ :> With[{m = Mean[s]}, m + Cross[# - m] & /@ s]}}]
```

[image: spin arrows a bit]

Answer (score 2):

Your own formula can be refactored in a more concise form:

```
f1 = With[{c = +##/2}, c + (# - c).{{0, -1}, {1, 0}} & /@ {##}] &;
```

- `+##/2` is a "trick" that here is equivalent to `Mean[{#, #2}]`
- the function needs to be applied with `@@@` rather than `/@`

A shorter function can be written using `Cross`, similar to what `J. M.` used:

```
f2 = {+##, # - #2}/2 &[+##, Cross[# - #2]] &;
```

Use of either function:

```
lines = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, {3, 2, 2}];

Graphics[{
  {Thick, Line /@ lines},
  {Red, Thick, Line /@ f2 @@@ lines}
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the OP reads:

`I want to rotate all of them by 90 degrees about their own centers`.

---

**Case-1:**

Treat all the line segments as separate and `Rotate` them about their own centers using the second argument of `RotationTransform` that is given by `Midpoint`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = RandomReal[{-3/4, 3/4}, {5, 2}];
lines = Line /@ Partition[data, 2, 1];
rlines = GeometricTransformation[#, 
     RotationTransform[π/2, Midpoint@#]] & /@ lines;

Graphics[{
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]
  , Point@data
  , Black, lines
  , Blue, rlines /. Line -> Arrow
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1.5, 0.5}}
 ]
```

[image]

**Case-2:**

Treat all the lines as a group and rotate about their shared center, as the accepted answer shows.

```
linegroup = Line@data;
Graphics[{
  Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]
  , Point@data
  , Black, linegroup /. Line -> Arrow
  , Blue
  , GeometricTransformation[
    linegroup, RotationTransform[π/2, Mean@data]
    ] /. Line -> Arrow
  }
 , Frame -> True
 , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1.5, 0.5}}
 ]
```

[image]

---

*Historical note:*

```
WolframLanguageData["Midpoint"
 , {"VersionIntroduced", "DateIntroduced"}]
```

[image]